# Unspecified Protractor error at the end of a test run

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have upgraded to Protractor 6.0.0 and Jasmine 3.3.1, and had to redo all my tests to run asynchronously.

When my Protractor test finishes running, I have an unexplained error at the end. No tests fail, but the process seems to abort irregularly. I am running against Chrome 73 in the latest webdriver, where I had to specifically downgrade to Chrome 73 webdriver because 74 is still in Beta.

Here is a snapshot of a test run:

> Test suite 1 Tests
>
> ```
> √ should check first thing
> √ should check second thing
> √ should display another thing
> ```
>
> Executed 3 of 94 specs INCOMPLETE (89 SKIPPED).
>   C:\Users\Joon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3190
>           throw arguments[0];
>           ^
>
> NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=73.0.3683.68
>   (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64)
>       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Joon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:585:15)
>       at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Joon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:533:13)
>       at Executor.execute (C:\Users\Joon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:468:26)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

There is no additional error message, the only other SO post I found that had the same error message also had an additional promise rejected error afterwards.

How can I debug / troubleshoot what is causing this error?

Comment: The session id refers to the instance of the browser that was launched by selenium (webdriver) and is used during your automated execution. Typically that error is received when the browser your tests were running on has been closed. Are you using any manually `browser.restarts` or `browser.close`?

Comment: @DublinDev no there are no calls to restart or close, however there were some browser.wait calls that I had not put an await in front of during the upgrade, and that was then causing a syncro issue with the browser state management at the end of the test run. I added await calls to all calls to browser.wait and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - there were some calls to browser.wait that did not have an await before them.

One of these was causing a synchronization error which led to that unspecified state management error at the end of the test run.

For anyone else experiencing WebDriver state errors after you upgrade from the control flow to the async flow - be sure to put await calls in front of all Protractor browser interaction calls. The one I had missed was browser.wait but it could be any other call to Protractor that causes this issue